# Modify foreign key to create a distributed database

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, distributed-database

I'm distributing a database but I have two tables with foreign keys references to the other database in other server. I have already searched and found that I can't make a foreign key referring to a table in another database in other server. But, how can I resolve this problem? Creating views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the instance that needs to refer to "the other server", introduce "the other server" as a linked server and then use INSTED OF triggers to validate the FK constraints.

Comment: yes, I get it, something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521(v=sql.105).aspx . So I must remove such foreign keys and whenever someone enters data in a table, the old foreign key field referred must be filled with a certain value of another table. So, I can also do this for input parameters in a stored procedure. thanks